# Scheduling a task run

Tags: ruby, architecture, system

I have a script that must run at a certain hour for the amount of time I specify.

I'm looking at the clockwork gem (https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork) which seems to be the closest piece of software I might eventually use to accomplish this, unfortunately it doesn't seem to give the ability to set a duration (start at 3PM stop 5PM), meaning I have to split the feature in 2, starting the script is going to be clockwork's job, stopping it is in the script itself with a custom solution.

Very suboptimal and messy.

How does people do this in Ruby? TIA

Answer (score 0):

There is great gem called [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) for same job. With it you can set exact time for your task, like:

```
every 1.day, :at => '4:30 am' do
  runner "MyModel.task_to_run_at_four_thirty_in_the_morning"
end
```

But you'll have to have two stages, one for starting one for stopping your job, which seems to be more natural than job which kills itself at some time by my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat janky, but there is another solution. I'm not sure what you are using to host your app, but on Heroku you can set up a [scheduler](https://addons.heroku.com/scheduler) to run every 10 minutes, on the hour, or daily. Then inside the method that the scheduler calls, you can determine the current time. Say you only want to run it between 3pm and 5pm, you would just wrap your code inside an if statement that verifies the current time is between 3pm and 5pm (watch out for time conversions with UTC).

Hope this helps.